# jQuery return key value [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some issue when I'm doing this:

```js
console.log(data);
var a = JSON.parse(data);
//console.log(a);
var prodName = a.productName; 
var splitProductName = "";
var prodQty = a.quota; 
var splitProductQuota = "";
var prodPrice = a.price;

jQuery.each(prodName, function(index1, value1) {
  splitProductName = value1;
  contents += "<tr>";
  contents += '<td>' + splitProductName;

  jQuery.each(prodQty, function(index, value) {
    if (index1 == index) {
      splitProductQuota = value;
      
      contents += '</td><td>' + splitProductQuota + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>';
      contents += "</tr>";
      // jQuery.each(prodPrice, function(index2, value2){
      //    alert(price_value_with_tax.value2);
      // });
      jQuery.each(prodPrice, function(index2, value2) {
        alert(price_value_with_tax.value2);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is the data result that is returned on the console (first line on the code).

```
{"quota":["14"],"price":[[{"price_id":"129","price_currency_id":"96","price_product_id":"127","price_value":"3.25000","price_min_quantity":"0","price_access":"all","price_users":"","price_site_id":"","price_start_date":"0","price_end_date":"0","price_value_with_tax":3.444999999999999840127884453977458178997039794921875,"taxes_added":true,"taxes":{"0000_00000003":{"taxation_id":"3","zone_namekey":"","category_namekey":"default_tax","tax_namekey":"GST","taxation_published":"1","taxation_type":"","taxation_access":"all","taxation_cumulative":"0","taxation_post_code":"","taxation_date_start":"0","taxation_date_end":"0","taxation_internal_code":"","taxation_note":"GST Tax Malaysia","taxation_site_id":"","taxation_ordering":"0","tax_rate":"0.06000","tax_ratio":1,"tax_amount":0.195000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875}}}]],"productName":["Baked Beans 230g"]}
```

But when I'm trying to get the `price_value_with_tax` it returns `undefined`. How am I supposed to code to get the value for `price_value_with_tax`?

Comment: Is `3.444999999999999840127884453977458178997039794921875` really the value of the `price_value_with_tax`? Does the code work if the number is like 3.45? (I'm wondering if this many decimal places is not parsing properly)

Comment: This data are parsing from Hikashop product sir. One of Joomla components. I just need to get the value and then will roundup to 2 decimal places when displaying the value on the frontpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(a);
var prodPrice = a.price;
jQuery.each(prodPrice, function(index2, value2){
    jQuery.each(value2, function(priceIndex, priceArr){
        console.log(priceArr.price_value_with_tax);
    });
});
```

[See attachment, object ref.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsV8t.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly reference the price_value_with_tax property in your JSON data.

Based on your sample, the property is at this location:

```
alert("value: " + a.price[0][0].price_value_with_tax);
```

Presuming that your sample data is just a snippet, you'll likely want to extract these values in some nested loops to iterate over the 2 arrays inside the price key.